# sql update add value one row to another row within the same table

Tags: sql

SQL update add value one row to another row with in the same table

```
UPDATE
   artigoArmazem
SET
  StkActual=  StkActual + StkActual2 
FROM 
  (Select StkActual FROM artigoArmazem  where artigo='110044' and Localizacao ='VIA1' and lote='<L01>' ) AS StkActual2 
artigoArmazem
```

Comment: You need to indicate what RDBMS you are using (mysql, sql-server, oracle, etc.) The format of your query appears to be malformed, but it's hard to tell without knowing your system. Also, you need to show the table definition, what are the columns and their data types?

Comment: Your query is really malformed. Please describe with words what columns hav eto be increased by what columns

Answer (score 0):

You just add them:

```
UPDATE artigoArmazem
    SET StkActual =  StkActual + StkActual2 
    WHERE artigo = '110044' AND  -- do not use quotes if the value is really a number
          Localizacao ='VIA1' AND
          lote = '<L01>';
```

`UPDATE` works one row at a time, so you are fine.  Things get trickier if you want to combine values from *multiple* rows.